# Assign value of variable in class C++

Tags: c++, class, object, reference

Hello I can't find out how to assign values to my variables that I am using in one of my class. I am getting error **nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object** so I am doing something wrong but I cant figure how o make it right.

```
class Triedenie_cisla{
    public:
        Triedenie_cisla(int *poleHodnot, int ddlzka); 
        int *pole, dlzka;  
        double bubble_time, selection_time, insert_time, quick_time;
        vector<int> mnozina_int;                   
        string vypis_pola();        
        void BubbleSort_int();      
        void SelectionSort_int();
        void InsertSort_int();      
        void QuickSort_int();
};
```

Then in functions that make sorts, I measure the time and trying to assign the time to variables like that

```
Triedenie_cisla::insert_time = dif;
```

What I am doing wrong ? Thanks

Comment: You must use the objects name instead the class name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find a good book on C++, those are basic things.

> nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object

means that to modify `insert_time` you must do it on existing object of class: `Triedenie_cisla`

> Then in functions that make sorts, I measure the time and trying to assign the time to variables like that `Triedenie_cisla::insert_time = dif;`

you should do it like that:

```
void Triedenie_cisla::BubbleSort_int() {
   // ....
   insert_time = dif;
   //
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an object of your class. Then, assigning values is possible.

```
Triedenie_cisla obj;
obj.insert_time = dif;
```

Otherwise, the compiler assumes that you want to change the value of a static variable, ie.
a variable that exists once for the whole class. To do so, you would have to state
that insert_time is a static variable.
For example:

```
static double insert_time;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it well, you wish to set the value of insert_time inside your own sorting function which are already part of the class Triedenie_cisla.

Therefore you just need to do

```
this->insert_time = dif;
```

or even

```
insert_time = dif;
```

would be enough

Answer (score 0):

You can not call a variable/method only using class name unless it is static variable/method of the class. Therefore, solution of your problem is:

**Solution-1**

First make a object of your class:

```
Triedenie_cisla object_1 = new Triedenie_cisla() ;
```

Call the variable using object name.

```
object_1.insert_time = dif;
```

**Solution-2**

You can solve this problem  also using static key word in front of insert_time in the class declaration:

```
static  double bubble_time, selection_time, insert_time, quick_time;
```

Comment: The solution 2 would be better, bacause I dont need to create objects, however when I use static I get this error 1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static double Triedenie_cisla::bubble_cas" (?bubble_cas@Triedenie_cisla@@2NA)